# Cant echo row mysql data on same page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Anyone know why i cant echo my DB row on same page with my Code?:

```
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['username']);


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM apiusers WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            echo $row[5];

        }


    }
```

This code is before `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the page.

Now i want echo this  `<?php echo $row[5]; ?>` in my body area, but dont show any results, why? In the code above works great.

Comment: How many columns in your table?

Comment: `In the code above works great.` But it's not showing any rows?

Comment: In the code before `<!DOCTYPE html>` it shows the results. but only if i use the full code it works in the body area, but it must works also with my `<?php echo $row[5]; ?>` line.

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense. Full code?

Comment: Full code: ` $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['username']);


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM apiusers WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            echo $row[5];

        }


    }`

Comment: needs `echo $row[5];` also the line `$sql =....`?

Comment: Well you're making an assumption that the code actually gets inside the query result loop. Put some debug 'echo' code outside the loop to verify that 1) the query didn't fail and 2) the query returned rows.

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` to see what you are actually getting. Also, please use [prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare) to avoid sql injections.

Comment: @billyflu Do you mean that the code in the original question is working, but you're trying to use `<?php echo $row[5]; ?>` outside of the code posted... and inside your html?

Comment: Yes correct @dustytrash . Sorry for my bad english:)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`<?php echo $row[5]; ?>` won't work inside the html page because the $row variable only existed within the while loop.

Declare a variable at the top instead. E.G:

```
$myQueryResults = array();
```

Change your while loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    array_push($myQueryResults, $row);
    echo $row[5];
}
```

Inside your body you can now use $myQueryResults

```
<html>
    <!-- echo the first result, row 5 -->
    <p> <?php echo $myQueryResults[0][5];?> </p>
</html>
```

Or print all elements:

```
<?php
foreach ($myQueryResults as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Where i must post ` $myQueryResults = new array();` exactly?

Comment: @billyflu Before the while loop, at the top of the page. Right before `$username` for example

Comment: Then i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY)

Comment: @billyflu my mistake, `$myQueryResults = array();` I updated it.

Comment: Yes that works great , many Thanks:)

Comment: *"the $row variable only existed within the while loop."* - This is not true. There's no such scoping mechanism in PHP. Try e.g. running `while ($x = 0) {}; echo $x;` at the REPL and observe that it prints `0` and does not emit a warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

Because `FALSE` is assigned to `$row` when the `while` loop exits, after the last rows is fetched.  (When there are no more rows to return, and the `fetch_row` function returns `FALSE`.)

Inside the loop, `$row` is populated.

If we need to reference the retrieved values later outside the loop, we need to preserve the values into a variable that we can reference.